# chmod all files (including hidden files) in a directory in Linux (not recursively)

Tags: linux, chmod, files

Yesterday I did something stupid which I today realised. I ran:

```
/root# chmod o-rwx * .*
```

This supposed to remove read, write and execute permissions for the world on all files in the current directory (`/root`). As soon as I did this, `screen` behaved weird, I couldn't run commands as a non-root user, and ssh refused to work unless I logged in with root.

This was caused by the fact that `bash` expanded `.*` to `..` too! Now, how do I chmod all files in a directory with `chmod`, without using `find`, a loop or another language like perl?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using bash then setting `dotglob` will make `*` also match files that begin with a `.`.

```
shopt -s dotglob
echo *
```

Comment: And for disabling it, `shopt -u dotglob` should be run. Thanks, if there is not other way, I'll accept this one I :)

Comment: The other way is `.[^.]* ..?* *`, but that leaves you open to problems if you don't use `nullglob`.

Answer (score 3):

You say "without using find", but find really is the right tool for this job because it provides a high level of control.  You can tell it to recurse or not, change directories or not, etc...  For example:

- All files in the current directory: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`
- All entries (files+directories+others): `find . -maxdepth 1`

Find doesn't normally distinguish between regular files and "hidden" files, but it does not include `..`.  If you want it to ignore them you can add `'!' -name '.*'`, if you want it to operate only on dot files you can add `-name '.*'`.

Another nice thing about it is that you can do the above, and it prints out the entries it will operate on.  So add "| less" to the end and you can eyeball what it will operate on before actually doing the changes.  This review step may have prevented the problem you saw.

Once you have a find command you like, you can get it to run the chmod command by adding `-exec chmod o-rwx '{}' ';'` to the end.  Change `';'` to `+` if your `find` version supports it.

Really, find is a tool you shouldn't be afraid to use in this sort of situation, it really is the right tool for the job.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid `find` is because it executes `chmod` for each file. Hence, it's a bit slower, but you're right, it is a very useful tool with many powerful possibilities. +1 for the detailed explanation.

Comment: The "+" will avoid executing a chmod for every file, but that's really only a consideration if you have more than a few thousand files.  Since you're talking about a single directory and not recursive, if you have enough files in there that this matters, you probably have bigger problems...  Also note that find+exec won't bomb out if your command-line gets too big, it will automatically run 2 or more `chmod`s.  If your find doesn't support "+", you can use "-print0" with find and then `| xargs -0 chmod o-rwx` to get the same results.

Answer (score 2):

It's short and cheerful, and not completely reliable in the sense that it misses dotfiles with odd names (eg `.+baz`), but as there are *very* few of those, I taught myself to do

```
chmod -R foo:bar * .[0-z]*
```